# Error installing perl Tk module using cpan

Tags: perl, cpan, perltk

I am trying to install Tk using cpan I get an error.  This is on a PC, Windows 10, Strawberry Perl 5.38.1

Attempting a basic install of the Tk module, everything downloads, makefile runs to a point, but then terminates on error.

I am using this at the command line:
cpan Tk

I get this error:

> In file included from ../pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/Xlib.h:31,
> from tkWinPort.h:19,
> from tkPort.h:32,
> from tk.h:87,
> from imgBMP.c:11:
> ../pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/X.h:182:34: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
> 182 | #define ControlMask             (1<<2)
> |                                  ^
> gmake[1]: *** [makefile:891: imgBMP.o] Error 1
> gmake[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/perl/cpan/build/Tk-804.036-2/pTk'
> gmake: *** [makefile:1638: pTk/libpTk.a] Error 2
> SREZIC/Tk-804.036.tar.gz
> C:\perl\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
> Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Tk'.

Here is the code section from X.h, with some context (error is on line 182):

```
    177: /* Key masks. Used as modifiers to GrabButton and GrabKey, results of QueryPointer,
    178:    state in various key-, mouse-, and button-related events. */
    179: 
    180: #define ShiftMask      (1<<0)
    181: #define LockMask       (1<<1)
    182: #define ControlMask        (1<<2)
    183: #define Mod1Mask       (1<<3)
    184: #define Mod2Mask       (1<<4)
    185: #define Mod3Mask       (1<<5)
    186: #define Mod4Mask       (1<<6)
    187: #define Mod5Mask       (1<<7)
```

I'm not sure what the compiler version is; it is whatever installed with Strawberry Perl, since I didn't have gcc/gmake installed previously.

Any suggestions? what do I not see? (btw: I checked - no funky characters hidden in the whitespace)
OR - is there a better way to install Tk? It kindof defeats the purpose of cpan if you have to go thru and edit the source.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/eserte/perl-tk/issues/87 and https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/98